# return all indices of first elements in a list where subsequent values increase incrementally

Tags: python, list, increment, indices

Need to find indices very similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70119439/return-the-index-of-the-first-element-in-the-list-from-where-incremental-increas)

But I have a list of multiple groups of incrementing values, e.g.
`lst = [0,1,2,7,8,9]`

Expected output: `[0,3]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version with a simple loop:

```
lst = [0,1,2,7,8,9]

prev = float('-inf')
out = []
for i,v in enumerate(lst):
    if v!=prev+1:
        out.append(i)
    prev = v
out
```

Same thing with a list comprehension and `zip`:

```
out = [i for i, (a,b) in enumerate(zip([float('-inf')]+lst, lst)) if a+1!=b]
```

Variant with [`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) (python ≥3.10):

```
from itertools import pairwise
out = [0]+[i for i, (a,b) in enumerate(pairwise(lst), start=1) if a+1!=b]
```

output: `[0, 3]`

Comment: @DanielHao unfortunately, yes. I added a note

Comment: Just try the `zip` version on this list - `lst = [1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 10]` but got `[0, 3, 4]`? Can you check? Should it be returned `[0, 4]` only. Not sure.

Comment: it should return `[0, 3, 4]` as `3` and `5` are not consecutive

Comment: Well, maybe I misunderstood, but it shouldn't change the underlying logic, you can use a different condition ;)